# Cocos 2D CCColor3b not assignable to property.color

Tags: objective-c, xcode, colors, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I am probably staring the answer in the face, however.

I want to assign a random colour to a `CCLabelTTF` string. When I try to set the return type of `(CCColor3B *)` and assign it `CCLabelTTF.color = [self randomColor]` I get incompatible assignment errors, both in the method, and at the above assignment. Method code:

```
-(ccColor3B *)randomColor
{
float r = arc4random() % 255;
float g = arc4random() % 255;
float b = arc4random() % 255;
ccColor3B *color =  {r,g,b,1};
return color;
}
```

I think I am trying to obtain a return value which is the wrong type, or assign a read-only value, but information on `CCColor3B` is scarce. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Cocos2d class documentation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/index.html), the property `color` of [CCSprite](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_sprite.html) is not a pointer (it is a struct)

> -(ccColor3B) color [read, write, assign]

You need to change your method as follows

```
-(ccColor3B)randomColor
{
float r = arc4random() % 255;
float g = arc4random() % 255;
float b = arc4random() % 255;
return ccc3(r,g,b);
}
```

You can find the definition of ccColor3B in the docs for [CCTypes.h](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/cc_types_8h_source.html) (line 43)

> typedef struct _ccColor3B {
>       GLubyte r;
>       GLubyte g;
>       GLubyte b; } ccColor3B;

Comment: There's also the shortcut method of ccc3(r,g,b). Your code also has an error where it uses the alpha component which ccColor3B doesn't have: {r,g,b,1} should be {r,g,b}

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thank you, I missed that because I was focusing on the pointer mistake from OP. I can't believe I missed that when I posted the typedef right there